# What is the type of variable is the RatingBar and how to obtain it?

Tags: android, eclipse, ratingbar

Sorry, I am new on this. Basically I thought of using the RatingBar to obtain the value and then send it over to a database over PHP. But I need to obtain the value and set it to float. Is there a more general example that I can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a ratingBar , use :

```
float value= ratingBar.getRating()
```

This is a basic [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/) to use RatingBar in Android

Comment: is it possible to convert this to string?

Comment: ratingBar.getRating().toString();